# How to calculate impulse response of discrete time system?

Tags: discrete-signals, self-study

$y(n)=n \times y(n-1)+x(n)$

$y(n)=$ output of causal Linear Time Invariant system
$x(n)=$ input of causal Linear Time Invariant system

$y(n)=x(n) * h(n)$

$h(n)= $system

Comment: Your system is not LTI because you're multiplying by n, so all bets are off.

Answer (score 3):

Paul R is right: your system in not time-invariant, so the impulse response doesn't mean much.  This could actually be a typing error o your site, more common is y(n) = k*y(n-1)+x(n). This being said, you can still calculate impulse response my simply starting at n = 0 and evaluate the difference equation one step at a time. For 1,2,3,4 ... so the impulse response would be h(n) = n.

However your last three sentence are not true. The system is not time invariant, convolution is meaningless and h(n) is not the system response.

Assuming difference equation is actually y(n)= k*y(n-1)+x(n), the answer would be quite different.With the same method you can determine the impulse response to be 1, k, k^2, k^3 .... So you have h(n) = k^n which would indeed be the system response and could be used for convolution.

Comment: Yes,you are right. It is not Time invariant but it is given problem that it is causal

Comment: still don't have an impulse response, because the system is not LTI.  if you bang this with an discrete-time impulse (kronecker) at $n=0$ or $\delta[n]$ you will get a much different response than if you bang it with an impulse at $n=5$ (or $\delta[n-5]$).  and it's much different besides being delayed by 5 samples.

Comment: now a time-variant linear system **can** have a time-dependent impulse response.  that is a function of two variables: $h[n,m]$ instead of $h[n-m]$ for the LTI system.  both represent the impulse response for an impulse applied at time $m$.